# Catan settlements on roads

Tags: catan

Let's say I have 4 connected roads with no settlements or cities in between.  Can I later go back and place a settlement in there?

Comment: Just be careful, because your opponent's could also come along with their own road pointing to the middle and build their own settlement there!

Comment: It says somewhere in the rules that if an opponent builds a house in the middle of your road it will break your longest road into two roads - which implies that people can build houses there.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, so long as it's not adjacent to another settlement.**

A valid location for a settlement is any spot that touches one of your roads, and is not adjacent to any other settlement.  I'll also note that it's legal for *someone else* to put a settlement in the middle of your road, so long as they also have a road that touches that intersection - this will cut your 4-segment road into two 2-segment roads, which can be a useful strategy for killing someone's longest road.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From [the rules](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_5th_ed_rules_eng_150303.pdf):

> Each of your settlements must connect to **at least** 1 of your own roads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can build a settlement if:

- You have a settlement left in stock
- You have the resources to build the settlement
- There is no adjacent settlement or city
- There is one of your roads or ships leading to the spot you want to build the settlement

So yes you can build one along the road.